# How to Change Jquery Menu Background Color?

Tags: jquery, menu

I have a Jquery menu and I would like to change background of it how can I do it ?

This is the website;
http://tinyurl.com/3g58vhb

Instead of Grey I would like to make it #4466DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to common.css, line 849. Where it says "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)", replace it with your color. I won't pretend to understand that CSS, but that works (If you were looking to understand that just ignore this answer)...

Also, if you want to find these things out, you can use Google chrome>inspect element>go to the element you want to change>expiriment.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:right;white-space:pre;color:#4466DD;">
```

Change the right value for color. ;)